# Global resets a pain with web components

Tags: css, native-web-component

I have a global reset like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Now if I define padding on a web component, I have to add `!important` to override the global reset, for example (in the shadow root styling):

```css
:host {
    padding: 16px !important;
}
```

Now say in some usage of the web component, in the normal DOM, I wish to override the the top padding to be 0:

```
wc-foo.special-case {
  padding-top: 0px !important;  /* <--- does not work */
}
```

The above does not work, because the earlier `!important` from the shadow root styles wins.

I wish to have styling that beats a css global reset, but looses to properties set on it in the light DOM, i.e. pretty normal cascading behavior. Is there anyway to achieve it?

I know I can do something complicated with `--css-custom-properies`, but when you are using a component, to hunt down what is the custom property to simply set the padding of an element not appropiate.

Comment: What's the order of importing the css files? You should import reset css first and then your custom css file

Comment: The CSS reset is in the normal DOM, the custom CSS is in its own web component javascript file as a constructed stylesheet, that comes later.

Comment: You should not have to ever use `!important`, that is a code smell, particularly if you are writing all the code.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be looking at is CSS specificity:
https://specificity.keegan.st/
classes with higher specificity will override classes with lower ones if you do not use !important.
Anyway, I do not recommend giving a padding and margin of zero to all elements but rather to the ones you don't want any on.
eg:

```
p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: also the :host pseudoelement is overridden by any of the outer classes * included

Comment: The specifity changes across the shadow boundry, so standard CSS specifity does not apply. Maybe research web components first.